# how do i forward traffic from port 80 to another port

Tags: ubuntu, odoo, iptables

I am running ubuntu and I want to forward requests from port 80 to another port i.e. 8069 where I am running my openerp server...

what rule or bash script do I need to solve this problem?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions; this does not appear to be a programming question.

Comment: Sorry, mr littlebobbytales, there are so many questions on this topic but I couldn't find an answer to this question, I do not see any problem asking this question... I need an ubuntu command if there is any

Comment: And I thought most commands under linux or ubuntu are done under bash within the terminal, so when i say command(s), doesn't that mean the same as a script? so what's wrong with the question? I have edited it anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, what you are referring to is called a reverse proxy, and you can set one up easily with Nginx

First, install Nginx

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Then start Nginx

```
sudo service nginx start
```

Visit your server's ip address to see if it's working. 
If you see "Welcome to nginx!", you're on the right track

Remove Nginx default configuration

```
sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

then

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Visit your server's ip address again. 
This time, you should see "503 Bad Gateway". It's ok, that's what you want

Next, make a new file

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/openerp.conf
```

Paste this into it, replacing "yourhostname.com" with your server's hostname (or the domain you will be serving this on, if you're putting it on the web)

```
#worker_processes  1;

#events {
#    worker_connections  1024;
#}

    server {
        listen  80;
        server_name yourhostname.com;
        location /socket.io {
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8068;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;

            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;

            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

            proxy_redirect off;
         }

        location / {
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8069;
        }
    }
```

Restart Nginx

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Now visit your server's ip address again. If you get the OpenERP login screen, you're good to go! If not, check the console for any errors starting nginx, fix /etc/nginx/conf.d/openerp.conf, and try again